# Make li item boxes pop out in order jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a footer list:

```
<footer id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2> x </h2>
            <h3> xx  </h3>
            <p>xxx</p>
            <p> xxxx </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2> x  </h2>
            <h3> xx </h3>
            <p>xx </p>
            <p> xx </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2> x </h2>
            <h3> xx </h3>
            <p>xx</p>
            <p> xxx</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

that pops out on click to two separate links, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
        $( "#footer" ).toggle( "fast" );
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "ul li:eq(3)" ).click(function() {
        $( "#footer" ).toggle( "fast" );
    });
});
```

I would like these ul boxes, after their current popout link is clicked, to either fill with content one after the other in order, or have the boxes themselves pop out one at a time.  Input wherever I can do better is helpful as well; I'm a rookie. Bonus: how to have the boxes revert in order when those two links in question are clicked again to close? Thanks all.

edit: the two links that pop out the footer are here, the contact link and the phone image:

```
        <section id="side">
            <nav class="sidebar"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></img>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="docs.html"> Providers </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Quality </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
                </ul>
                <img id="add" src="images/phoner.png"></img>
            </nav>
        </section>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what your code is producing against what is expected. I actually couldn't reproduce much in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m173gxvg/, could you modify it to have exactly what you see?

Comment: Where is the `#add` button? What is "*[the] current popout link*"? "*how to have the boxes revert in order when tab is clicked again to close?*" - which is the tab that's clicked (and then clicked again to close)? Please take a read of the "[mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" guidelines, and the "[ask]" page to try and improve your question so that it can be understood and then solved.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti https://jsfiddle.net/m173gxvg/2/

Comment: OK, gotcha. I see that the 3 footer boxes pop out simultaneously, and I understand that you want them to pop out one after the other instead. Did I get it right?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti exactly

Comment: You have two `ul` elements, and you have a selector: `ul li:eq(3)`, which list should this select an `<li>` from?

Comment: @DavidThomas the nav list, specifically the "contact" link,  posted at the end of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $footer = $("#footer").hide(),
        $footerItems = $footer.find("ul li").hide(),
        footerState = 0;
    $("#add, .sidebar ul li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        footerState = !footerState;
        var method = footerState ? 'show' : 'hide';
        if(footerState) $footer.show();
        $footerItems.get().reduce(function (p, li) {
            return p.then(function() {
                return $(li)[method]('slow').promise();
            });
        }, $.when()).then(function() {
            if(!footerState) $footer.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m173gxvg/10/)**

Comment: Almost exactly this, except with the boxes at their full size, so they pop out in order as they do here, but the individual boxes themselves do not grow or shrink

Comment: Try changing `'show' : 'hide'` to `'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'`

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/m173gxvg/3/

Something like this? If yes, here are the modifications:

> Remove the display:none from the footer css
>   Add the display:none to the footer ul li css
>   Modify the javascript code

Here's the js to use after the click:

```
toggleTimer=500;
    $( "#footer" ).find("ul").find("li").each(function() { 
        jQuery(this).toggle(toggleTimer);
        toggleTimer=toggleTimer+500;
    });
```

Comment: Close, thank you, this behaves a little erraticly, on my browser at least

Comment: What do you mean by erraticly? What kind of browser are you using? If you would like a smoother effect, you can change the addition of the toggleTimer line.

Comment: Not sure I can describe it, just glitchy movement when being toggled off especially, in all my browsers.  Is there a way to pop them out in order as you've done, without the growing and shrinking of each individual box while they're popping up/out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to click on each one and then show the next one, is that right?
Then you can use the .next() jquery property to assign the click listener to toggle the next element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //start with all LI hidden
    $('#footer').find('li').hide();
    //add click listener to the id='add' element to toggle the first LI
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
            //if none are visible, show the first one, else hide them all
            if ($('#footer').find('li').first().css('display') == 'none' ) {
                //show the fist LI
                $( "#footer" ).find('li').first().toggle( "fast" );
            } else {
                //hide them all
                $('#footer').find('li').hide();
            }
        });
    //add listener to each LI to toggle the NEXT one
    $('#footer').find('li').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

... after your comment...

OR You can show the FIRST hidden one on each click like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //start with all LI hidden
    $('#footer').find('li').hide();
    //add click listener to the id='add' element to toggle the first LI
    $( "#add" ).click(
        function() {
            //if NO LI are hidden, hide them all, else show one at a time
            if ( $('#footer').find('li:hidden').size()==0 ) {
                //hide them all
                $('#footer').find('li').hide();     
            } else {
                //show the first hidden LI
                $('#footer').find('li:hidden').first().show('fast');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I'm hoping to have them pop out all at once, just one after the other, on the same click

Comment: OK - I've added to my answer to allow you to click the same button to display the <LI> in order. :)